# Why the limit of $\sqrt{n}$ sample variance is variance?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, variance, asymptotics

For the mean $\bar{X_n}$ of n iid normal observations with $EX=\mu$ and $\operatorname{Var}X=\sigma^2$, if we take $T_n=\bar{X_n}$, then $\lim \sqrt{n}\operatorname{ Var} \bar{X_n}=\sigma^2$ is the limiting variance of $T_n$.

I don't understand this. I know $\operatorname{ Var} \bar{X}=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$. Hence if we multiply it by  $\sqrt{n}$, I think the limit will tend to 0, since we have $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}$.

Comment: $Var(aX)=a^2Var(X)$. Please note the power, i.e. $^2$.

Comment: @Tan I know this equation. But what does this matter with my question?

Comment: I believe it should be $\lim\text{Var}(\sqrt{n}\bar{X}_n)=\sigma^2$